# jQuery-ui draggable error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a page with divs that you can move..

And now to my problem:
Everytime i move a div i get this error

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined
var o = $(this).data("ui-draggable").options;
```

Here's a picture of my boxes:
[image]

As you can see the green boxes floats to the left, the first time i'm going to move it..

Why is that? Can i change that so it doesn't move that much?

Here is my code right now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9G9dR/

Comment: You have not included jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: Yes i have? jquery.min

Comment: Why are you setting both sortable and draggable? Can this fit your needs http://jsfiddle.net/33V9T/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting both sortable and draggable?

You can use only `sortable` with `connectWith`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Sortable').sortable({
        connectWith: '.Sortable'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/33V9T/